# Apache 2.4 and server-info authentication access

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to set up /server-info on my apache 2.4 (debian jessie) install.

I'd want to give access to server-info through an authentication process, like the one I can define via an .htaccess file, but I can't find a directory in which I should place the necessary files.

Is it possible to give access to server-info via username-password?

Comment: The obvious answer is yes. You can add an authentication requirement to the Location section for [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html).

Comment: What directive should I put there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) is enabled for a **`Location`** you need to add your authentication requirements to that location as well. The manual gives the following example:

```
<Location "/server-info">
    SetHandler server-info
    Require host example.com
</Location>
```

where is access is restricted to visitors from  `example.com`.

But instead you can use any one (or more) of the other methods Apache supports for [authentication and authorization](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) as well.

For instance configuring [basic authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html) would look something like this:

```
<Location "/server-info">
    SetHandler server-info
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Server Info is a restricted resource: please authenticate"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
    Require user rbowen
</Location>
```